# Open a folder with the default file browser

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a button in my app named "open the folder". On click, I want to simply open a folder with the default file browser of the device if one installed(ie: astro).
With "open a folder" I mean to delegate to the file browser the management of the specific location, showing its content.

I have tried with `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with no luck.

Here is one example(it gives me an error: "no activity found to handle intent...")

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(myFolderURI, "file/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` to your intent?

Comment: Tryed, same error, thanks anyway

Comment: It might just be that the file-browser app doesn't support the intent...

Comment: On the device I use OI file manager, I'll try with another FM

Comment: Tryed with astro installed too. Same error...

Comment: Another quick thought -- there are a number of apps in the market which explore the installed packages and especially the intent filters they have registered. Why don't you see if anything in the default FM or the third-party ones points to a browse-folder intent?

Answer (score 1):

After many things I tried, the only way it worked was by wrapping the URI string into a File first, and then do a Uri.fromFile:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyDownloadedFiles/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.action_downloaded)));
```

See more info: [Open folder on card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855837/open-folder-on-card/)