# Open folder on card

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I thought this was something really simple, but it's giving me more work than the rest of the whole app.

I just want a button to open the "Downloaded Files" folder of my app. That's all. No file picker, nothing complicated. All the button has to do is open a folder with the default app (or open the app chooser if there's no default).

I tried different solutions I saw here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work for me.

Example 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyDownloadedFiles/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.action_downloaded)));
```

On my Android 4.4, this opens the KitKat file picker, and doesn't even open in the folder I want... it seems to be defaulting to the card root. But I'm sure the folder exists and the path being given to the Intent is indeed correct.

Example 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyDownloadedFiles/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.action_downloaded)));
```

This one opens some blank activity with a popup saying: "Error occurred when getting file Content: MyDownloadedFiles".

**How can I make my app to simply have a shortcut to a folder where it puts contents into?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wow.. Finally!! After many things I tried, the only way it worked was by wrapping the URI string into a File first, and then do a Uri.fromFile:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyDownloadedFiles/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.action_downloaded)));
```

Comment: So, the combination of that conversion (sound really strange) and `"*/*"` is the key? Not `"*/*`alone? Or maybe, the conversion alone?

Comment: I think the key thing here is that the File object may prepend "file://" or whatever, which makes it to work. "*/*" isn't for sure the solution, because if I use "Uri.parse()" and "*/*" in the type, it won't work - will do the same as my Example 1 above.

Comment: It is strange to me that you keep "not writing" the asterisks (*)... Anyway, if kitkat requires it to be done that way, you can simplify the code a bit if you keep in mind that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` already gets you a File object (better keep it simple so we don't create a myth of going from File to String to File to Uri :P). Congrats!

Comment: Oh, the asterisks didn't appear because they transform to bold. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem. Anyway, this question has been a good reminder for keeping us on our toes with each Android release :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this one could work for you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/yourFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open /sdcard/yourFolder"));
```

Comment: Hello. I tried that already, and it's pretty similar to my Example 1. The only difference is the type. I tried with */* before I went with text/plain.