# Sharing Audio files only works with some apps

Tags: java, android, libgdx

It seems that I am getting bug. At least I think its a bug. I coded a kind of Soundboard and wanted to add the ability to share the sounds with others. My code to share is as following:

```
public void share(Sound sound) {
    //libgdx command to copy an internal file(classpath) to external memory
    //sound.file is the relative path to the audio file that will be shared
    Gdx.files.internal(sound.file).copyTo(Gdx.files.external("/skrelpoid/KJ/share/" + sound.file));
    String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/skrelpoid/KJ/share/" + sound.file;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
    //app is the main application
    app.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Teile den Sound"));
}
```

The problem I have is that this works, but only with some apps. For example, when I shared the audio with WhatsApp or with DropBox it seemed to work perfectly fine, but when I try to do the Same with Google Drive or Bluetooth there seem to be some errors. Note that the filetype of the audio is WAV. I also made sure that I have permission to write to the external storage, but still only some apps work. I am really lost on this and would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: "Note that the filetype of the audio is WAV" -- then use the MIME type for WAV. Use `MimeTypeMap` to look it up, since there seem to be a few possible MIME types. As it stands, receivers have no idea what the file format is.

Comment: I don't understand how it will help e.g. Google Drive that it knows the filetype it is uploading. Why would it even need to know, it just uploads it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like The error is because of `Uri.parse(str)`.
The following code (Which is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856099/)) seems to work:

```
public void share(Sound sound) {
    Gdx.files.internal(sound.file).copyTo(Gdx.files.external("/skrelpoid/KJ/share/" + sound.file));
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/skrelpoid/KJ/share/" + sound.file);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(sound.getExtension()));
    app.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Teile den Sound"));
}
```